# Compile Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: php, inno-setup, phpdesktop

I want to create an php site into exe file. so thatI am using Innoscript software to create exe files..  while compiling the inno script error will be occurred

> Compile Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

```
#define MyAppName "indexapp"
#define MyAppVersion "0.0.1"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "phpdesktop-chrome.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{890F1243-E039-4AE5-8407-A5D227471A18}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=C:\Users\VEPL-PHP\Desktop\setup
OutputBaseFilename=setupindex
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\phpdesktop-chrome.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\cef.pak"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\d3dcompiler_43.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\d3dcompiler_46.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\debug.log"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\devtools_resources.pak"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\ffmpegsumo.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\icudt.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\libcef.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\libEGL.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\libGLESv2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\license.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\settings.json"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\locales\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\php\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\webcache\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\xampp\htdocs\phpdesktop old - Copy\www\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Can you post the log? Can you check the process tree and find out that which is the another process?

Comment: Please include a complete output of the Inno Setup compiler.

Comment: no log file generated while compiling

Comment: error is occurred out cannot be generated

Comment: "error is occurred out cannot be generated" - what does that mean?

Comment: Compile the script from command-line using `ISCC.exe`

Comment: I am new to desktop-application.  What is ISCC.exe file? sry for the inconvienence.. plzz help me..   thank you

Comment: It's Inno Setup command-line compiler. It's part of Inno Setup installation.

Comment: C:\>iscc "F:\xampp\htdocs\isetup"
'iscc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. this error is occured  ***IN command line execution*

Comment: You have to use a full path to the `iscc.exe`, something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe`.

Comment: C:\>C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\isetup
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  again this error is occrred

Comment: You have to enclose the path to double-quotes, as it contains spaces. Like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe"` + Make sure you use a path to the `.iss` as the argument, not just path to the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Stopped OneDrive and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with other software you're running on your computer. Try closing all programs including those running in background. Found a similar issue caused by the Sync program:

> The only way to use Innosetup in combination with Sync is to: close
>   Sync, run Innosetup, restart Sync to synchronize the new file.

https://forum.getsync.com/topic/32041-sync-14-file-replacement-issue-can-cause-file-loss/

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn off Dropbox and Avast antivirus. After, the error immediately went away. One of these probably locked some files.